# Binding SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, xamarin

How can i bind SelectedIndexChanged of a picker? im working on an mobile enrollment project, where the user have to pick a block or section in order to load the schedule for the picked block or section.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow but in order to find quality help you will need to provide more information than that. Please visit this link for more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, if my answer helped to you, please mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can bind your picker's SelectedItem.

In view model.

```
  private YOURTYPE mySelectedItem;
  public YOURTYPE MySelectedItem
        {
            get => mySelectedItem;
            set
            {
                mySelectedItem= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
            }
        }
```

In Xaml:

```
 <Picker x:Name="myPicker"
         SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}" 
         Title="Select something"
         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"       
        VerticalOptions="Center"></Picker>
```